# Pandas read_csv() not reading column containing web links or any column after

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-sheets

I am trying to remove duplicates from a CSV I created via webscraping and using the following to create the CSV:

```
Greensboro_Parks = pd.DataFrame({"Mobile Home Park":pd.Series(company_names),"Phone Number":pd.Series(company_phone),"Website":pd.Series(website_link_list),"Street":pd.Series(company_street),"City/State":pd.Series(company_locale)})

Greensboro_Parks.to_csv('Greensboro_Mobile_Homes.csv', index = False, header = True)
```

Link to CSV on Github (screenshot file was to large):
https://github.com/sdejewski10/Upwork_Mobile_Homes/blob/master/Greensboro_Mobile_Homes.csv

When I open a new file and read the CSV in, it only displays the first two columns: "Mobile Home Park", and "Phone Number". I tried opening the CSV file in Google Sheets and it also only displays the first two columns. I've come to the conclusion it is likely related to the formatting of the weblink trying to be read into the CSV?

I tried using:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/steve/Documents/Coding/Upwork/Mobile Homes/Greensboro_Mobile_Homes.csv', usecols = ['Mobile Home Park', 'Phone Number', 'Website', 'Street', 'City/State'], dtype= str)
```

OUTPUT:
`ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Website', 'Street', 'City/State']`

I've reviewed:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html but could not interpret how to format the URL to be read. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You exported your csv file using `header=True` so you you don't need to specify `usecols` when using read_csv. In general, if column names are provided in a csv file, you can use the `header` argument to give the row number corresponding of the column names.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I tried initially without specifying the column headers and it still only imports the first two columns: Mobile Home Park and Phone Number. 

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Is the Greensboro_Parks DataFrame having such columns ? You can use a basic .head() to display a sample of it, or even .columns. 
It seems that at the moment you export to a csv file, they are already missing.

Comment: I just updated with the link to the CSV file i created and then trying to read in. It contains all the columns when exported to Git and viewed in VS Code. But when I use Pandas or Google Sheets to read the CSV File, only the first two columns appear.

Comment: I just downloaded the csv and opened it with a simple pd.read_csv and it worked just fine. All the columns are there

Comment: Tried with sheets as well, all the columns there too

Comment: Interesting, I downloaded the file from Git into a new file and still only get two columns in Sheets and Pandas. I am stumped.

Comment: Just in case, you can try updating pandas ?